# Read owl file using python flask

Tags: python, owl

Hi I am new to python and owl. I have installed python flask for developing web applications. I have created a simple hello world code. Please help me in displaying the owl file contents. I want to load the owl file and display its contents using python flask. Please help me.

The following code is sample code for printing hellowworld. I want to load and display an Owl file contents in web. I have stored my owl file locally. How will i achieve this?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

Comment: and you could not find any OWL library for Python?

Comment: check the answer though this is not full traceback you might be missing `cups.h`

Comment: I have attached an image for your reference. please go-through it and let me know what the error is.

Comment: The following is thrown when tried to install manually. **error: can't copy './hermit/org/semanticweb/HermiT/cli': doesn't exist or not a regular file**

Comment: Still getting the error **error: can't copy './hermit/org/semanticweb/HermiT/cli': doesn't exist or not a regular file**

Comment: Please tell me why i am getting this error

Answer (score 2):

Install [this](https://pypi.org/project/Owlready2/) package

```
pip install Owlready2
```

You can read like this

```
from owlready2 import get_ontology

onto = get_ontology("file:///home/jiba/onto/pizza_onto.owl").load()
#You can access the elements by `.` operator
onto.Pizza
```

**EDIT**

If you are facing errors while installation you are missing `cups.h`

Resolve it by

```
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
```

Comment: Even I tried installing manually. **error: can't copy './hermit/org/semanticweb/HermiT/cli': doesn't exist or not a regular file**

Comment: Can you post this traceback in your question edit it, It is hardly readable here

Comment: When I tried your code I got the error. 
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from owlready2 import get_ontology
  File "/home/gayathri/microblog/owlready2/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from owlready2.base            import *
  File "/home/gayathri/microblog/owlready2/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    import sys, os, types, tempfile, subprocess, weakref, re, urllib.request, warnings, itertools
ImportError: No module named request
**